# nhibernate child collection

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, database, nhibernate

So let start from code itself:

```
public class Site
{
    private Int32 id;        
    private string name;
    private IList<SiteDomain> sitedomains;

    public Site()
    {
    }

    public virtual Int32 Id
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; }
    }

    public virtual IList<SiteDomain> Domains
    {
        get { return sitedomains; }
        set { sitedomains = value; }
    }

    public virtual string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }
}

public class SiteDomain
{
    private Int32 id;
    private string domain;

    public SiteDomain()
    {
    }

    public virtual Int32 Id
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; }
    }

    public virtual string Domain
    {
        get { return domain; }
        set { domain = value; }
    }
}
```

So as you can see I don't need any link to Site from SiteDomain. But I want to have a list of site's domains in site entity.

Here is DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE `site` (
    `id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
ENGINE=InnoDB;


CREATE TABLE `sitedomains` (
    `id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `siteid` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `domain` VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `sitedomains_siteid` (`siteid`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_sitedomains_siteid` FOREIGN KEY (`siteid`) REFERENCES `site` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
)
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Mappings I got at the moment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" namespace="PhoneTracking.Core" assembly="PhoneTracking.Core">
  <class name="Site" table="site">
    <id name="Id" type="Int32">
      <column name="ID" not-null="true" />
    </id>
    <property name="Name" type="AnsiString" />
    <list name="Domains" cascade="all">
      <key column="SiteId" />
      <index />
      <one-to-many class="SiteDomain" />
    </list>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" namespace="PhoneTracking.Core" assembly="PhoneTracking.Core">
  <class name="SiteDomain" table="sitedomains">
    <id name="Id" type="Int32">
      <column name="ID" not-null="true" />
    </id>
    <property name="Domain" type="AnsiString" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

It retrieves very well when I get a Site. It comes with all associated site's domains. But then I save new Site back to DB it save only site itself without inserting site's domains.

How should I make it right?

I know about NHibernate's ISet. I just want to make it IList because it more comfortable for me.

---

EDIT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" namespace="PhoneTracking.Core" assembly="PhoneTracking.Core">
  <class name="SiteDomain" table="sitedomains">
    <id name="Id" type="Int32">
      <column name="ID" not-null="true" />
    </id>
    <property name="Domain" type="AnsiString" />
    <many-to-one name="Site" column="siteid" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" namespace="PhoneTracking.Core" assembly="PhoneTracking.Core">
  <class name="Site" table="site">
    <id name="Id" type="Int32">
      <column name="ID" not-null="true" />
    </id>
    <property name="Name" type="AnsiString" />
    <bag name="Domains" inverse="true" cascade="all">
      <key column="SiteId" />
      <one-to-many class="SiteDomain" />
    </bag>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Updated SiteDomain class:

```
public class SiteDomain
{
    private Int32 id;
    private string domain;
    private Site site;

    public SiteDomain()
    {
    }

    public virtual Int32 Id
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; }
    }

    public virtual Site Site
    {
        get { return site; }
        set { site = value; }
    }

    public virtual string Domain
    {
        get { return domain; }
        set { domain = value; }
    }
}
```

Here is how I try to save new dynamically created entry:

```
ITransaction tx = session.BeginTransaction();

Site s = new Site();
s.Name = StringGenerator.RandomString(20) + " site";
s.Domains = new List<SiteDomain>();
s.Domains.Add(new SiteDomain { Site = s, Domain = StringGenerator.RandomString(20) + ".com" });   

session.SaveOrUpdate(s);                
tx.Commit();
```

And now I get an exception:

> {"could not insert: [Project.Core.SiteDomain#0][SQL: INSERT INTO
>   sitedomains (Domain, siteid, ID) VALUES (?, ?, ?)]"} : {"Cannot add or
>   update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`project`.`sitedomains`, CONSTRAINT `FK_sitedomains_siteid` FOREIGN
>   KEY (`siteid`) REFERENCES `site` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE
>   CASCADE)"}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `IList<>` is maped via `<list>` you should provide a mapping for index column: see [6.3. Collections of Values and Many-To-Many Associations](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#collections-ofvalues). Extract:

> For indexed collections like maps and lists, we require an  element. For lists, this column contains sequential integers numbered from zero. Make sure that your index really starts from zero if you have to deal with legacy data

So, there must be also column for index in your "sitedomains" table. If there is now index column you can still use `IList<>` but mapped via bag:

```
<bag name="Domains" cascade="all">
      <key column="SiteId" />    
      <one-to-many class="SiteDomain" />
</bag>
```

NOTE: Also be sure that your collection is instantiated e.g.:

```
public Site()
{
   sitedomains = new List<SiteDomain>();
}
```

EDIT: cannot use `siteid` **NOT NULL**

The mapping you've used, does not contain `inverse` mapping. `SiteDomain` does not reference the `Site`. That means that NHibernate has to insert the `SiteDomain` entity into its table, and in the second step, it updates the `siteid` column with a reference to `Site`.

Becuase the `siteid` column is NOT NULL, you get the exception.

Solution, 1) mark the column as NULL or 2) change your mapping to reference the `Site` from SiteDomain and change the mapping to be inverse like this:

```
 <bag name="Domains" cascade="all" inverse="true">
    <key column="SiteId" />    
    <one-to-many class="SiteDomain" />
  </bag>
```

and use many-to-one in the Site mapping

```
<many-to-one name="Site" column="siteid" />
```

And finally when adding the `SiteDomain` into `Domains` collection, you also have to set SiteDomain.Site = site

```
site.Domains.Add(siteDomain);
siteDomain.Site = site;
```

That will instruct NHibernate what is the siteid value, and only one insert will be applied. And the NOT NULl constraint could be still applied

Comment: I make it bag, and it helps in some part. At the moment, I use bag and when I try to save Site to database, exception is arises: [Project.Core.SiteDomain#0][SQL: INSERT INTO sitedomains (Domain, ID) VALUES (?, ?)] : {"Field 'siteid' doesn't have a default value"}. How can I manage with that issue?

Comment: I updated my answer. The problem is in the NOT NULL setting of your siteid column.

Comment: Please see my updated answer for you. Still same exception. Maybe we should look at the column generator?

Comment: In this case, it will be the fact, that you did not set the reference in code. When adding the SiteDomain into Domains collection, you also have to set `SiteDomain.Site = site`

Comment: Radim, I already do that. The thing that helped me to manage this issue is to define id generator as "identity" that forces nhibernate to persist entity before using it.

Comment: Briliant job. Glad to see that you've managed to make it working. NHibernate is a bit challenging to learn, but the benefits awaits you ;)